# How to get parameter long html page string from request in java?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I post request in javascript. I send html page in post data. In java, i use `String html = request.getParameter("templateHtml");` I see html string in request, when i was debug mode. But "html" variable is null. 
my javascript code is here:

```
var postData = {};
postData["templateHtml"] = "Html page's string is too long";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: createUrl,
    data: postData,
    success: function(data) {
      onSuccess(data);
    },
    error: function(message) {
      onFail(message);
    },
});
```

Why am I receiving a null "html" variable? How can I fix it?

Comment: where is "html" variable?

Comment: "String html = request.getParameter("templateHtml");"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var postData = {};
postData["templateHtml"] = "Html page's string is too long";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: createUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function(data) {
        onSuccess(data);
    },
    error: function(message) {
        onFail(message);
    },
});
```

I convert my post data to JSON. It's working now.